# "Graph Execution Error" in Machine Learning and TensorFlow Project

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, layer

I am a student and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. I don't know why I am getting this error. Any questions or specifications about the code I am happy to answer to clarify anything. If anyone has any insight I would greatly appreciate it.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

    train_idg= ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255,
                               shear_range=0.2,
                               zoom_range=0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = False,
                               vertical_flip = True,
                               )

    train_data = train_idg.flow_from_directory('rps_train',
                                           target_size=(64,64))
                                           #,class_mode='binary')
    #Found 2520 images belonging to 3 classes.

    test_idg = ImageDataGenerator(1./255,
                             shear_range=0.2,
                             zoom_range=0.2,
                             horizontal_flip = False,
                             vertical_flip = True,
                               )
    test_data=test_idg.flow_from_directory('rps_test',
                                       target_size=(64,64))
                                       #,class_mode='binary')

    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    from tensorflow.keras import layers

    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=64,
                        kernel_size=3,
                        input_shape=[64,64,3],
                        activation='relu'))

    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(strides=3))

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=32,
                         kernel_size=3,
                         activation='relu'))

    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(strides=3))

    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(units=64, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'] )

    model.fit(x=train_data, validation_data=test_data, epochs=10,batch_size=50)

And the error appears here.

Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [29], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(x=train_data, validation_data=test_data, epochs=10,batch_size=50)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in 
filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:54, in 
quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)

 52 try:
     53   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs' defined at (most recent call last):
```

The error code goes on with directory names, etc.... I am really not sure what to do or what I've done wrong and my professor is not super helpful so I am grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues here. According to the comment, your data is:

```
#Found 2520 images belonging to 3 classes.
```

Since there are 3 classes, you should use 3 units in the last layer (and not 64):

```
model.add(layers.Dense(units=3, activation='softmax'))
```

Furthermore, the loss should be "sparse_categorical_crossentropy". The "binary_crossentropy" can be used only if you have 0/1 labels.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't get a chance to upvote the other day. I appreciate the insight.